# Handling answer-related promotion (on old posts)

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

A user/his posts were marked as possible vandalism ([Rook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183528/rook)) due to a bunch of edits of some older answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325622/438992), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5074429/438992), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2995386/438992), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602980/438992), [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305435/user-input-filtering-do-i-need-to-filter-html/2307669#comment10800076_2307669)). All edits were changes to point to a site he's associated with.

I left comments linking to the [promotion FAQ entry](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) but nothing came of them.

The FAQ states that affiliation must be disclosed. All the answers are related, relevant, and reasonable.

Were my comments too much, given it's not spam? No axe to grind; just curious.

Comment: Dave, in the case of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5074429/109702), why didn't you just edit the answer and change the last line to make it more explicit, instead of just leaving a comment (and possibly flagging it for spam)? The answer had some merit, but now it is deleted - all it needed was a minor edit.

Comment: @slugster While I have no issues editing for grammar, spelling, formatting, etc., I'm far less amenable to making "I"/"my" statements in someone else's voice. I also prefer that people handle situations like this themselves after being informed of site norms. I feel I spoke plainly, and explicitly, when I said the answers were related, relevant, and reasonable, and weren't spam--somehow you missed that.

Comment: The added links were certainly spam going by the site guidelines, and possibly had accumulated a number of flags by the time you saw it. In any case Bill has undeleted that particular answer, and I've added a footnote to it. Your comment was fine but over the New Year period a comment could go unseen for some time, and with a number of people chasing flag weight instead of actively improving answers it was doomed. Your link #1 is definitely 100% spam - even with disclosure it was nothing more than a link answer with no supporting explanation and would have been VLQ/NAA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, those comments weren't too much.  I've contacted the user privately.